# sentence embeddings for alternatives of a word in a sentence

Tags: nlp, word-embedding

Looking for Embeddings which can throw the alternatives of a given word in a sentence looking at the context info.

Ex:

> I read a great book at lunch.

Generated sentences:

> I read a good book at lunch.
>
> I read a good novel at lunch.
>
> I read an excellent book at lunch.
>
> I read an excellent novel at lunch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.